# Failed to Raise Network interfaces Debian 9 Fresh

Tags: linux, debian, networking

i have a Debian 9 64bit server and fresh installed. Just noticed that the Networking manager is not working properly since my Webinterface kinda doesnt like that.

```
root@mail:/etc/network/interfaces.d# ifup -v eth0

ifup: configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet) /bin/run-parts
--exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant /bin/ip addr add
173.212.217.24/255.255.255.0 broadcast 173.212.217.255           dev eth0 label eth0 RTNETLINK answers: File exists ifup: failed to bring up eth0
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you ifup a interface that is already working, you will get that error. It is not clear what is your question. Also, you are not telling us that you are trying to do a bridge between eth0 and wifi. I advise investing much  more time on writing better questions

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the bridge and wpasupplicant scripts are just plugins that will see they have nothing to do and will do nothing.

Comment: @A.B nowadays. this question is from 4 years ago.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it was the same even then. ifupdown (version 1) hasn't changed much. I just mean that OP  probably didn't attempt to use a bridge or Wifi despite the verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the network to come up when it is down, the config for that situation should be in ifdown, when it comes up it should run ifup because it is now up. You should not have to manualy run those files, it should be automatic based on the state of the network interface.

- If the network is down it should autorun ifdown.
- If the nework is up it should autorun ifup.